# How do I select the button that is clicked, from a multitude of similar buttons, from the following code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a vote up/down functionality on comments.

For that, I've placed two buttons in every comment. Using jQuery's each() and click() functions, I am trying to get the button's id that was clicked, fire an ajax request to aother page, and then disable both vote up/down buttons for that specific comment using the success() callback.

For initial verification of whether it works or not, I'm trying this on just two comments i.e. 4 buttons, and then disabling a specific pair of them, irrespective of which button is clicked.

I've tried 3-4 different selector queries, but the only one that works is where I specifically pass the exact id attribute's value of the button that I click on. I need to implement this in a general fashion, on a page with multiple comments and their buttons!!

Here's the PART of the HTML code on which I'm trying to use the jQuery:

```
<section class="section content">

            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="zone-content equalize zone clearfix">
                    <div class="content-container container-16">
                        <div class="comments block">
                            <div class="block-title-2">
                                <h2>Comments on Place X</h>
                            </div>
                            <div class="review-messages">

                                <div class="review first">
                                    <div class="review-author">
                                        <b>
                                            <span class="author">John</span> - <span class="date">April 10, 2013 at 7:34 pm</span>
                                        </b>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="review-text">
                                        Best place to have abcdef food in yyyyy. !!!
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                <!-- xxxxxxx SELECT ONE OF THESE TWO -->   <button class="btn btn-circle btn-success" id="test_id_1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></a></button>
                <!-- xxxxxxx SELECT ONE OF THESE TWO -->  <button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger" id="test_id_2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i></a></button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="review last">
                                    <b>
                                        <div class="review-author">
                                            <span class="author">John</span> - <span class="date">April 10, 2013 at 7:34 pm</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </b>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="review-text">
                                        <p id="text1">Great xxxx and a good place to yyyy :)</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                <!-- xxxxxxx SELECT ONE OF THESE TWO -->    <button class="btn btn-circle btn-success" id="test_id_3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i></a></button>
                <!-- xxxxxxx SELECT ONE OF THESE TWO -->   <button class="btn btn-circle btn-danger" id="test_id_4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i></a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-message">
                                <div class="comment-message-title">
                                    Leave a <span class="text-colorful">Comment</span>
                                </div>
                                <form class="comment-message-form">
                                    <textarea class="text-input-grey comment-message-main" placeholder="Your Comments Here"></textarea>
                                    <div class="thin-separator"></div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="button-2-colorful to-right" value="Post Comment" name="comment" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div><!-- end of .content-container -->

                </div><!-- end of .zone-content -->
            </div><!-- end of .content-wrapper -->

        </section>
```

Here are the various jQuery selector codes I've tried:
1. **DOESN'T WORK**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div button[id^="test_id_"]').each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(e){
            var name = {"name":$(this).attr("id")};
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'receiveajax.php',
                    data: name,
                    type: 'POST',
                }).success(function(data) {

                        $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                    });

                    });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

2. **DOESN'T WORK**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function(e){
                $('button[id^="test_id_"]').each(function(){
            var name = {"name":$(this).attr("id")};
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'receiveajax.php',
                    data: name,
                    type: 'POST',
                }).success(function(data) {

                        $(this).attr("disabled",true);

                    });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

3. **SPECIFIC ELEMENT SELECTOR QUERY. WORKS.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test_id_1").click(function(e){
            var name = {"name":$(this).attr("id")};
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'receiveajax.php',
                    data: name,
                    type: 'POST',
                }).success(function(data) {

                        $("#test_id_1,#test_id_2").attr("disabled",true);
                    });
      });
   });
   </script>
```

And this is the page that  will receive the Ajax POST request, implemented as a simple stub. I've also used it's echo output in the success() callback to print it, so as far as I'm concerned, this file doesn't have any errors. Probably. :

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your loops are complex which is not need.
2) Inside the `success` callback, `this` is not your button, you should keep a reference to it.
3) Using `prop` for `disabled` attribute is preferred.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e){
        var $button = $(this);
        var name = {"name": $button.attr("id")};

        $.ajax({
            url: 'receiveajax.php',
            data: name,
            type: 'POST',
        }).success(function(data) {
            $button.prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked!! I also disabled the button's other voting counterpart using siblings(), and displayed a "Opinion registered" <p> tag for 1.5 seconds!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close but you don't need to iterate buttons using `.each()`, simply bind click event and you will get instance of clicked button i.e. `$(this)` and use that instance to disable the button. see below code -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button[id^="test_id_"]').click(function(e){
            var name = {"name":$(this).attr("id")};
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'receiveajax.php',
                    data: name,
                    type: 'POST',
                }).success(function(data) {

                     $(this).attr("disabled",true);

                });
      });
   });
   </script>
```